# How to create a Google Drive Spreadsheet using Google Drive Android Api

Tags: android, google-sheets-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm creating an app where the user can select items from a listview and I want to send that data and create a new Google Drive Spreadsheet with that data in it. This is my first time with the API, and I really have no idea what I'm doing. I've followed the demo tutorials they have on GitHub, and I was able to create the screen where the user can choose the folder in their drive to send the data, but I don't know how exactly to send the data. In this method:

```
final ResultCallback<ContentsResult> contentsCallback = new ResultCallback<ContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(ContentsResult result) {
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setMimeType("text/html").build();
            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .setInitialContents(result.getContents())
                    .build(getGoogleApiClient());
            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(
                        intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
            }
        }
    };
```

Do I have set the metadata to the data I want to send? I basically want to be able access certain sheets and rows and columns of a spreadsheet, and I haven't found a way to do it. I'm really confused. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive Android API does not know anything about spreadsheet, image, text,... It deals with objects that have metadata, that specify what the object (file, folder) 'looks' from the outside. Metadata specify its title, description, starred status, ownership, relation to parents, etc....
And it also has content, which you can write or read as a byte[] buffer. If you write spreadsheet, jpeg image, or whatever, the API does nor know about it.

Here is a code some snippet to help ('await' flavor to make look simple):

```
GoogleApiClient _gac;
...
// parentEID - parent Encoded DriveID ("root" for root, "appfolder" for appfolder)
// name - file name
// mime - mime type
// buf - data to write 
void create(String parentEID, String name, String mime, byte[] buf) {
  try {
    DriveFolder pFld = getFldr(pEID);
    if (pFld != null) {
      MetadataChangeSet.Builder bldr = 
                               new MetadataChangeSet.Builder().setTitle(name).setMimeType(mime);
      MetadataChangeSet meta = bldr.build();
      ContentsResult ctR0 = Drive.DriveApi.newContents(_gac).await();
      if ((ctR0 != null) && (ctR0.getStatus().isSuccess())) {
        DriveFileResult dfRt = pFld.createFile(_gac, meta, ctR0.getContents()).await();
        DriveFile dFil = (dfRt != null) && dfRt.getStatus().isSuccess() ? 
                                                            dfRt.getDriveFile() : null;
        if (dFil != null) {
          ContentsResult ctR1 = dFil.openContents(_gac, DriveFile.MODE_WRITE_ONLY, null)
                                                                                  .await();
           if ((ctR1 != null ) && (ctR1.getStatus().isSuccess())) {
             ctR1.getContents().getOutputStream().write(buf);
             Status stts = dFil.commitAndCloseContents(_gac, ctR1.getContents()).await();
             if ((stts != null) && stts.isSuccess()) {
               MetadataResult mdRt = dFil.getMetadata(_gac).await();
               if ((mdRt != null) && mdRt.getStatus().isSuccess())
                 Metadata md = mdRt.getMetadata();
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {}
}
// eid - Endoded ID produced by DriveId..encodeToString() 
DriveFolder getFldr(String eid) {
  DriveFolder dFld = null;
  if (eid != null ) try {
    if (eid.equals("root")) {
      dFld = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(_gac);
    } else if (eid.equals("appfolder")) {
      dFld = Drive.DriveApi.getAppFolder(_gac);
    } else {  
      dFld = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(_gac, DriveId.decodeFromString(eid)) ;
    }
  } catch (Exception e) {}   
  return dFld;
}
```

So, you call this method, specify where it goes (parent ID), the file name, its mime type, and binary content. The file will show up in the Google Drive (if you got through the authorization gauntlet - but this is another story). BTW, I'm assuming you're talking about an Android app, right?
good luck

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about android. How do I specify which rows/columns the data goes into?

Comment: As I said, you can copy the entire object (spreadsheet) from your app to Google Drive. The 'byte[] buf' variable above would contain the spreadsheet. Google Drive Android API does not deal with spreadsheet specifics like rows / columns. See https://developers.google.com/drive/android/get-started

Comment: Alright, so what you're saying is that I can set the spreadsheet data in the `byte[] buf` variable, but there's no way to deal with spreadsheet specifics? So there's no way I can put the data into a specific row/column?

Comment: There is probably a way to deal with spreadsheets on Android  (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/), but it has nothing to do with Google Drive API. This API deals only with creation and manipulation of Drive objects. I tried to help with the Drive upload problem and know nothing about spreadsheets API.